# Why do I need to call Navigator.of(context).pop() twice?

Tags: flutter

I have a dialog, with a widget that calls Navigator.of(context).pop() when the application window is resized (think Windows, Web, or changing portrait<>landscape on phones).

This works and the dialog closes.

However, if there is a ModalBottomSheet active when Navigator.of(context).pop() is called, only the ModalBottomSheet closes and I need to call Navigator.of(context).pop() again.

As a workaround this is what I have done. `cameraSelectorWidget` is a bool that is true of the ModalBottomSheet is active.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(); << called in the build method
  if (cameraSelectorWidget) {
   _popAfterWaitingForCameraSelectWidget();
}

Future<void> _popAfterWaitingForCameraSelectWidget() async { 
  while (cameraSelectorWidget) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    if (!cameraSelectorWidget && mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am unhappy with this 'hack'. What am I doing wrong?